# Excel - Incrementation at each change in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to increment numbers in the B column at each change in the A column.

Example:(below attached image)

[image: Incrementation at each change in another column]

Any help please?
Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Bob.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with pure Excel.  You might have to write some VBA code to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B1+1,B1)
```

[image]

Just drag down the formula in B2...

Or in case you don't have headers but your data starts in A1:

```
IF(ROW(A1)>1,IF(A1<>INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)-1),INDIRECT("B"&ROW(A1)-1)+1,INDIRECT("B"&ROW(A1)-1)),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Write 1 for the B1 cell. From the B2 cell, insert the form below.

```
=IF(A2=A1;B1;B1+1)
```